# ember-cli-jstree actionreceiver is null

Tags: ember.js, jstree

My environment version is as below:
version: 1.13.1
node: 0.12.4
npm: 2.12.1
when ember-cli-jstree is installed, I use the component in this way:

```
//hbs file
{{ember-jstree
  actionReceiver=jstreeActionReceiver
  data=data
  eventDidBecomeReady="handleTreeDidBecomeReady"
  }}
and

//controller
App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
jstreeActionReceiver: null,
data:[],
action:{
handleTreeDidBecomeReady:function(){
      console.log(this.get('jstreeActionReceiver'));       
      }
}
})
```

the jstreeActionReceiver is null,So what the mistake I have made?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? that the action receiver is null? youre setting it to null `App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
jstreeActionReceiver: null,`

Comment: I registered it to js tree's actionReceiver

Comment: `console.log(this.get('jstreeActionReceiver'));`  -- this line will output `null` because 4 lines above it it is set to null. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I thought when js tree is ready the actionReceiver value will passed to jstreeActionReceiver so it will not be null.

Comment: To be honest Im not familiar with jsTree but setting the receiver to null like above doesnt seem correct. Have you tried removing that line of code?

Comment: @Craicerjack I found the answer :https://github.com/ritesh83/ember-cli-jstree/issues/17,thank you.

Comment: Glad you found an answer